# How to use facebook batch request to get share count of multiple urls in one request

Tags: java, facebook, batch-processing

I have my website which has different article pages almost 1000. I want to get facebook share count for all article pages. I am trying to use url with comma separated urls for article pages

http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=art1url,art2url

But it does not give me the complete JSON i always get different results for urls like if i made hit with 30 urls sometimes it give hit for 20 urls and sometimes for 25 urls but not consistent
Could you please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the link_stat FQL table (see docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/) as follows:

```
select url, click_count, comment_count, like_count, share_count, total_count from link_stat where url in ('{url1}', '{url2}', ...)
```

I'd recommend that you use not too big batches of URLs, because the overall length of an FQL statement is not allowed to exceed 2048 characters.

Comment: Hi #Tobi i tried this approach but when ever i made request it gives me 400 error. I am using java. It is working fine when i use this on browser.

Comment: You need to URLencode this and use the endpoint /fql?q={your_urlencoded_query} to be able to do this!

Comment: Ya i did that but still same issue.

Comment: This is my URL                        https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url in ("http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fentertainment%2Fbollywood%2Fxpose-theatrical-trailer-ft-himesh-reshammiya-yo-yo-honey-singh-irrfan-khan-138822.html","http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fboyz-toyz%2Fmachines%2Frobots-to-operate-on-astronauts-in-space-138860.html","http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fnews%2Findia%2Fmen-get-narendra-modi-fever-gujarat-poll-widows-138877.html") I am using java to hit this URL

Comment: It returned different exception in that case java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Ffql%3Fq%3DSELECT+url%2C+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url+in+%28%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fentertainment%2Fbollywood%2Fxpose-theatrical-trailer-ft-himesh-reshammiya-yo-yo-honey-singh-irrfan-khan-138822.html%22%2C%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fnews%2Famericas%2Fin-pics-shooting-at-fort-hood-in-texas-138814.html%22%29

Comment: You shall not encode the URL parts. Only the QUERY like this: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT%20url%2C%20share_count%20FROM%20link_stat%20WHERE%20url%20in%20(%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fentertainment%2Fbollywood%2Fxpose-theatrical-trailer-ft-himesh-reshammiya-yo-yo-honey-singh-irrfan-khan-138822.html%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fboyz-toyz%2Fmachines%2Frobots-to-operate-on-astronauts-in-space-138860.html%27%2C%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiatimes.com%2Fnews%2Findia%2Fmen-get-narendra-modi-fever-gujarat-poll-widows-138877.html%27)

Comment: Did this work for you? If so, please accept the answer.